# Do any good libraries and/or tools exist for automatic image "merging"?

Tags: image-manipulation

I am looking for a tool or library which will allow me to, very quickly, merge two source images, and generate a third, merged image, into a file.

My source data are two images in various formats (jpg, png, pdf, etc..), and instructions which identify which portions of the images are to overlap/merge.

By "merging" I mean any kind of transition effect from one image into the other - anywhere from, at the very simple end, an overlap with one image on top, to funkier things, such as automatic blending of colors and shapes.

I don't have a preference in terms of language and/or platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with ImageMagick, you can also use the [montage command line tool](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php) to merge images.

Answer (score 0):

I used a DLL called [CoolWaterMark](http://www.imagecomponent.net/) with pretty good success.

Comment: sorry, for some reason I keep "ASSuming" that this site is dedicated to .NET when it's not.  The above DLL is for .NET

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick's various [composition](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/) effects can be used for this.